# Unable to ping device with Jumbo Packets (MTU 9000) - Default ping error message, not because of MTU

Tags: networking, ethernet, ping, mtu, jumbo-frames

@Admins: [the question linked](https://superuser.com/questions/1107646/jumbo-packet-ping-from-pc-windows-10) addresses a different problem. My issue is specific to the fact that ping doesn't return a *MTU too small* message but a *general fail* message, pointing to a problem downstream.

I need to set up a local connection between my Windows 11 PC and an external device (IP 10.0.0.10), with jumbo frames enabled (MTU 9000).

At the end of the post, I put the steps I followed to set the MTU.

However, I still cannot ping my device with a large packet size. The strange thing is that I get a *default* ping fail message, and not a *packet too large* ping fail message.

To compare, let me show you the result of a normal ping (#1), a ping with a packet too large (#2), and a ping with a packet that should be handled by the jumbo frame (#3).

```
# 1.
ME> ping 10.0.0.10
Envoi d’une requête 'Ping'  10.0.0.10 avec 32 octets de données :
Réponse de 10.0.0.10 : octets=32 temps<1ms TTL=64

# 2.
ME> ping 10.0.0.10 -f -l 10000
Envoi d’une requête 'Ping'  10.0.0.10 avec 10000 octets de données :
Le paquet doit être fragmenté mais paramétré DF.

# 3. 
ME> ping 10.0.0.10 -f -l 8200
Envoi d’une requête 'Ping'  10.0.0.10 avec 8200 octets de données :
Délai d’attente de la demande dépassé.
Statistiques Ping pour 10.0.0.10:
    Paquets : envoyés = 1, reçus = 0, perdus = 1 (perte 100%),
```

To summarize, #1 returns a ping, #2 returns a packet too large error, and #3 returns a default error.
As you see, behavior #1 and #2 are normal, but not #3. The packet size is not too big to be handled by MTU (or else, I would have had the same error as #2).

I looked this problem up online and the answer I found was: my PC is configured correctly, but the receiving device does NOT have a MTU big enough. However, this device is specifically made to handle these large packets, I contacted the device's maker and they told me that it natively handles jumbo frames.

Where does this problem come from and what can I do to send large packets to 10.0.0.10 ?

The problem seems to be on my connection, but I can't find anything.

---

### Steps followed to set MTU

1. Powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\me> Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty "Ethernet*" -DisplayName "Jumbo Packet" -RegistryValue "9014"
PS C:\Users\me> Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty
Name                      DisplayName                    DisplayValue                   RegistryKeyword RegistryValue
----                      -----------                    ------------                   --------------- -------------
(...)
Ethernet 4                Jumbo Packet                   9014 Bytes                     *JumboPacket    {9014}
(...)
```

2. Command line:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "Ethernet 4" mtu=9000 store=persistent
netsh interface ipv4 show subinterfaces

       MTU  État détect supp      Octet entrant     Octet sortant  Interface
----------  ---------------  ------------  ------------  -------------
(...)
      9000  5             0             0  Ethernet 4 - Adaptateur TPL Blanc
(...)
```

3. `ncpa.cpl` (Network administration tool):

- Ethernet 4 --> configure --> advanced --> Jumbo Packets --> 9000

Comment: Which device is it?

Comment: Homemade electronics from a third-party company using a Xilinx Spartan FPGA, connected via Ethernet

Comment: Is the sending host on the same subnet (including the same subnet mask) as the target host? Did you confirm that the target host (and any routers in between) are set to generate and pass ICMP error messages as needed? It should be on by default, but make sure you haven’t disabled it or blocked it with a firewall setting or something. Did you use a packet sniffer to see if the target host is generating the required ICMP error packets?

Comment: @Spiff thanks for the answer. I disabled every firewall setting. I just sniffed using Wireshark and I can see that the pings are sent but get no reply. I made a few screenshots here with default packet size, 1000 packet size (works), and 4000 and 8972 packet size (no reply). https://imgur.com/a/fyD2gIX

Comment: It sounds like you’ve proved that the device you’re pinging isn’t doing the right thing, at least not for pings. You might want to do a different kind of test to see if it handles full 9k sized TCP segments or UDP datagrams correctly; maybe it’s only mishandling jumbo ICMP echo requests.

Comment: I'm currently reinstalling the firmware on the device to see how it behaves. I tested UDP with Wireshark and end up with a lot of "port unreachable" errors.

Comment: So, turns out that the device is not made to handle jumbo packets from ICMP, but using a custom protocol on portt 6006. So it's actually not supposed to accept pings with an MTU of 9000. I think we can close the question, thanks a lot all for your input.